# I have a problem in proof of $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}=0$

Tags: limits

Can we say that $x>0$ when $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}=0$, because x approaches to $\infty$?

Is the following proof correct?

step1:
$$|\frac{1}{x}-0|<\epsilon,M<x,0<x$$
step2:
$$\frac{1}{x}<\epsilon,M<x$$
step3:
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}<x,M<x $$
step4:
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}<M$$

Comment: This is too disorganized to allow a verification.

Comment: Try writing sentences with words instead of just a mass of symbols.

Comment: No, this is not a valid proof. Just independent expressions vaguely related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of a limit, we must have

$$\forall\epsilon>0:\exists M:\forall x> M:\left|\frac1x-0\right|<\epsilon.$$

This is true, because with $M=\dfrac1\epsilon$, we do have

$$\forall x>M:\left|\frac1x-0\right|<\epsilon.$$

So for all $\epsilon$ we can find an $M$ that fits.